# More Exacting A Wave

Tags: wave-equation

I have a strange wave and I am trying to make it an equation. These are the points I have plotted:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $8$ |
| $\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{4}$ | $\sqrt{128}$ |
| $\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{10}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\arcsin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}$ | $8$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$ | $\sqrt{128}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{10}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\frac{\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\pi$ | $8$ |
| $\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$ | $\sqrt{128}$ |
| $\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{10}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ | $8$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$ | $\sqrt{128}$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{80}}{10}\right)$ | $\sqrt{80}$ |
| $\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{3\sqrt{40}}{20}\right)$ | $\sqrt{40}$ |
| $2\pi$ | $8$ |

My only problem with this is that I haven't gotten to this kind of math yet, as I am only in 11th grade. I tried using a Lagrange Interpolation, but it was too chaotic. All I need is a wave that doesn't exceeds the height of $y = \sqrt{128}$ and doesn't go below $y = \sqrt{40}$ . The one reason I couldn't make this one is that the middle of the wave $y = 8$ isn't actually the midline and the wave has a higher amplitude on the top of and lower below the wave. Hopefully, you all can possibly come up with an equation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have multiple waves, and a constant term. By looking at the data, and playing a little with the numbers, I've got afunction that approximates your data quite well:
$$y=A[\cos(k(x+\varphi))+\cos(2k(x+\varphi))]+B$$
with $A=\frac{\sqrt {10}}2$, $B=8$, and $\varphi=\frac{\pi}4$. The blue lines (and circles) are your initial data, the red is the function.

It is also possible that you have a few more frequencies.

[image]

Comment: My only question. What is the variable k supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I've used $k=4$

Comment: Thank you! But I have a concern, I have graphed this out in desmos and it doesn't seem to match up the same as it did in your picture. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/usumrqyipo

Comment: Sorry, I used cos, not sin. I've edited my answer

Comment: This is helpful thank you! You must have accidentally used sine instead of cosine in your original equation, no worries though. Again thank you!

Comment: The reason one uses cosine is that the maxima/minima align at double frequency, while for the sine one aligns the middle